# Why does my UIStackView still show children when theyve been removed

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Im trying to create a remove an arranged subview from my stackview however when I try to do so the actual view is gone but it still ocupies space. Is there any way to avoid this?

heres my onClick method:

```
@objc func OnTrashButtonPress(sender: UIButton) {
        let view = sender.superview
        view!.isHidden = true
        StackView.removeArrangedSubview(view!)
        view!.removeFromSuperview()

        }
```

heres what my view normally looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opcrj.jpg

and heres what im it looks like when i delete a view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKBqq.jpg

im basically trying to get the views underneath to move up and fill the empty space but I don't think thats happening because the view isin't being properly removed? I cant seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Edit: heres the code that actually adds the view:

```
for (i, course) in response!.enumerated(){

            var courseView = CourseView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 415, height: 160))
            if let mark = course["mark"] as? CGFloat{
                courseView.ProgressBar.value = mark
            }else{
                courseView.ProgressBar.isHidden = true
                courseView.NATextView.isHidden = false

            }
            courseView.PeriodNumber.text = "Period: \(i+1)"
            if course["Room_Number"] != nil{
                courseView.RoomNumber.text = "Room: \(course["Room_Number"]!)"
            }
            if course["course"] != nil{
                courseView.CourseCode.text = (course["course"] as! String)
            }
            if course["Course_Name"] != nil{
                courseView.CourseName.text = (course["Course_Name"] as! String)
            }
            StackView.addArrangedSubview(courseView as UIView)
            print(courseView as UIView)
            courseView.TrashButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OnTrashButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
            courseList.append(courseView)

            StackViewHeight.constant = StackViewHeight.constant + 175

        }
```

Comment: You "may" need to use [`UIStackView#removeArrangedSubview(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616235-removearrangedsubview) as well

Comment: You might want to try `stackView.layoutIfNeeded()`after removing a subview.

Comment: Yea I tried that too, still no luck. ill update the post

Comment: Could you please share the code constructing View Controller? Maybe the problem is not because of the error you made when you remove the subview but because you have added two subviews that look the same. So you did remove the latter subview but the former is still there.

Comment: @YamingLin posted it

Comment: Maybe you could try courseView.height += 175?

Answer (score -2):

Wow ok. So for anyone that stumbles upon this in the future and is on the brink of insanity, heres how i solved it. Apparantley when you add a UIView from an XIB file you need to call superview twice like so: `let view = sender.superview?.superview` in order to get the actaul superview of the delete button